# D3 How to get the number of 'rows' from tsv data?

Tags: d3.js, csv

First time using D3 and I'm stuck on something I think should be simple:

I'm trying to make a percentage width bar chart SVG and I'd like to set the width of each bar to be the number of 'bars' it will be creating.

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.browser); })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return (100 / d.browser.length);})
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.time); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.time); })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {return "#"+d.colour;})
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

The key part that isn't working being this: `.attr("width", function(d) { return (100 / d.browser.length);})`

Which doesn't work. Here is a sample of my TSV data:

```
    test    browser time    colour
1 - attr selector   Chrome  65  fad009
1 - attr selector   Firefox 125 dd8e27
1 - attr selector   Opera   72  cc0f16
1 - attr selector   IE9 140 27b7ed
1 - attr selector   Android-4   120 80bd01
2 - attr qualified  Chrome  64  fad009
2 - attr qualified  Firefox 132 dd8e27
2 - attr qualified  Opera   78  cc0f16
2 - attr qualified  IE9 120 27b7ed
2 - attr qualified  Android-4   145 80bd01
```

Both column 1 and 2 are constants in that they are only ever one of 5 values and whilst I can hard-code 20% in there I'd like to set it properly so that is I add another set of results it still spaces correctly.

My JS-fu is weak so feel free to patronise me like you were teaching a child ;)

Any thoughts?

Further to request for for code:

```
    // Adapted from http://bl.ocks.org/officeofjane/7315455
var margin = {top: 45, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 200},
    width = 850 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 90 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");


var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

// Scales. Note the inverted domain fo y-scale: bigger is up!
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>" + d.test + "\t" + d.browser + "</strong><br/><span style='color:#fff'>" + d.time + " ms</span>";
});

// csv loaded asynchronously
d3.tsv("data2.tsv", type, function(data) {

    // Data is nested by country
    var selectorTests = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.test; })
        .entries(data);

    // Compute the minimum and maximum year and percent across symbols.
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.browser; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(selectorTests, function(s) { return s.values[0].time; })]);

    // Add an SVG element for each country, with the desired dimensions and margin.
    var svg = d3.select("#selectors").selectAll("svg")
    .data(selectorTests)
    .enter().append("svg")
    .attr({
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "100%"
    })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
    .attr("pointer-events", "all")

    .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", "0")
        .attr("y", '-100%')
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("font-size", "1.1em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.key;});

    // Accessing nested data: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/kummm9mS4EA
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.browser); })
        .attr("width", data.length)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.time); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.time); })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {return "#"+d.colour;})
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
        svg.call(tip);
});

function type(d) {
    d.time = +d.time;
    return d;
}
```

If I just use `data.length` I get '10' which is the total number of 'entries' (apologies I probably have completely incorrect terminology here) - I want/expect to see '5' as that is the number of bars that get created with each instance give the data. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Should be just `data.length` if `data` is what you get from `d3.tsv`.

Comment: Could you share your entire Javascript code?

Comment: You can look into the histogram layout. Or , look into the ordinal scale. The ordinal scale will space bars evenly with equal width

Comment: @LarsKotthoff if I use data.length I get 10 back which is the current amount of data (1 have 2 SVGs being made) but I expect to see 5 as that is the number of bars in each SVG made from the data. Added full code above in the hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: The second part of [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/) (using an ordinal axis) should help. In general, this would be the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's useful to visualize how you're data is being formatted and "passed around":

d3.nest returns your data in this format:

```
[
   {key: "1 - attr selector", values: [
     {test: "1 - attr selector", browser: "Chrome", time: 65, colour: "fad009"},
     {test: "1 - attr selector", browser: "Firefox", time: 125, colour: "dd8e27"},
     ...
   ]},
   {key: "2 - attr qualified", values: [
     {test: "2 - attr qualified", browser: "Chrome", time: 64, colour: "fad009"},
     {test: "2 - attr qualified", browser: "Firefox", time: 132, colour: "dd8e27"},
     ....
   ]},
   ...
]
```

Then you have two subsequent calls to `data`: one in the svg definition and another one in the first code snippet you posted. After the first one the `d` element will be of the form

```
{key: "1 - attr selector", values: [
     {test: "1 - attr selector", browser: "Chrome", time: 65, colour: "fad009"},
     {test: "1 - attr selector", browser: "Firefox", time: 125, colour: "dd8e27"},
     ...
]}
```

And this is where you should call `d.values.length` to get the number of browsers for that specific test.

After the second call to `data`, where you do `.data(function(d) {return d.values;})` each `d` element is in the form

```
{test: "1 - attr selector", browser: "Chrome", time: 65, colour: "fad009"}
```

And you see that at this point calling `d.browser.length` will return the length of the string with the browser name - not really what you want.

You have to get the number of browser before calling `data` for the second time, but you have to use it after calling it - that's the problem. You need to get the parent datum.
I hope I made the problem clear to you.

Talking about solutions, there are several. I'm not sure but `d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().length` or `d3.select(this).node().parentNode.__data__.length` or something similar instead of `d.browser.length` could work. Or you could remember the length in a variable (better, an array: each test could have a different number of browsers it was tested on) out of the selection and then use it.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense at all. In particular the first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: I wouldn't say incorrect, maybe just phrased badly. The core point is that the `d` parameter, after `data()` has been called, is a single line of data. I've rephrased it, but not sure if better.
Anyway, much of the answer depends on the data  manipulation he does, since in order to do what he wants to do he has to do some and can't just use the data as returned by `d3.tsv()`

Comment: @LeartS I just added the full JS I'm using above. Hope that helps (data as is original question)